# SnowflakeSQLException Error code: 390100, Message: Incorrect username or password was specified

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Connected to snowflake using python JDBC driver but not able to do that with pyspark in jupyter notebook?Already confirmed correctness of my username and password.

Environment details :-

- windows 10
- python 3.6.6(jupyter notebook)
- spark 2.4.3
- snowflake-jdbc 3.8.1
- spark-snowflake_2.11-2.4.13-spark_2.4

Referring this tutorial

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/spark-connector-use.html#label-spark-options.

[image: run pyspark with packages]

Error stack:-

[image: error stack]

Any Leads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to contribute to community posting answer

1. Following the version of spark and driver solved the problem:
   below combination of jars and spark worked for me.
       Spark 2.3.3 (spark-2.3.3-bin-hadoop2.7)
       Python 3.6.6(can be 3.7)
       snowflake-jdbc-3.6.12.jar
       spark-snowflake_2.11-2.4.8.jar
       snowflake server:-(3.27.2)
2. If you come across below error

   ```
   Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o272.load.
   : java.sql.SQLClientInfoException: The only allowable value is 
   application name.
   hodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   ```

   Remove **sfAccount** property from config sfOptions object
   [official snowflake document](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/spark-connector-use.html#setting-configuration-options-for-the-connector)

   ```
   sfOptions = {
       "sfURL" : "<account_name>.snowflakecomputing.com",
       "sfAccount" : "<account_name>",
       "sfRole" : "<user_role_name>",
       "sfUser" : "<user_name>",
       "sfPassword" : "<password>",
       "sfDatabase" : "<database>",
       "sfSchema" : "<schema>",
       "sfWarehouse" : "<warehouse>",
   ```

   }

Error thrown is pretty much generalized which further create confusion what was wrong or missed anything to add extra.

Comment: Thanks! Removing sfAccount was exactly what I needed

Answer (score 1):

to add to the community post and the correct answer, this also works with:

- spark version 2.4.3
- scala version 2.11.12

and the following jars:

- snowflake-jdbc-3.9.0.jar
- spark-snowflake_2.11-2.5.1-spark_2.4.jar

but you need to remove "**sfAccount**" from snowflake documentation for **sfOptions**

```
var sfOptions = Map("sfURL" -> "xxx.snowflakecomputing.com","sfUser" -> "your_sf_user","sfPassword" -> "your_sf_password","sfDatabase" -> "your_sf_database","sfSchema" -> "your_sf_schema","sfWarehouse" -> "your_sf_warehouse")`
```